# How to whitelist Country for ModSecurity Rule?

Tags: mod-security

I managed WordPress Site but the editors and contributors do get a lot of false-positive flags by ModSecurity which affected their publishing experience. so I intend to just whitelist the country where they are publishing from.

My problem is that I am not that good with ModSecurity rule configuration so am not sure if what I have prepared is correct.

Secondly, How do I get the legacy version of GeoLiteCity.dat?

Below is what I have put together

```
# Allow NG Country
SecGeoLookupDb /usr/local/geo/data/GeoLiteCity.dat
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,phase:2,id:1100234,allow,msg:'Custom WAF Rules: Allow NG Country'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq NG"
```

Answer (score 2):

With this rule, you allow clients from country with `NG` country code - but you newer denied the other countries.

You should try this:

```
SecGeoLookupDb /usr/local/geo/data/GeoLiteCity.dat
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "id:1100234,phase:1,drop,msg:'Custom WAF Rules: Allow NG Country',chain"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@streq GB"
```

As you can see, the main difference between this any your rule is that the disruptive action is not `allow`, but `drop`.

Please note, that you can use this rule in `phase:1`.

> Secondly, How do I get the legacy version of GeoLiteCity.dat?

I'm not familiar with license, but this is what I found:

https://mailfud.org/geoip-legacy/

Edit: you can find more information about `GEO` variable [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#GEO).